# Unknown column "X" in field list on delete, but the column exists

Tags: mysql, update, delete

I'm using MySQL and i'm trying to run a delete statement as follows:

```
DELETE FROM `myTable`
 WHERE `nincidusua` = 84
```

and the following error occurs:

> Unknown column 'nincidusua' in 'field list'

My first thought was that the column was inexistant, but it trully exists, when i run this simple `SELECT`:

```
SELECT nincidusua FROM myTable
```

it works completely normal:

```
DESC myTable
```

shows the column on the list and even selecting the columns from `information_schema` shows up the column name and its structure.

I noticed that the same error happens on `UPDATE` queries, because I had the idea to create a dummy column, save the data from the faulty column and then recreating it, but when I try running:

```
UPDATE myTable SET DUMMY = nincidusua
```

the error persists.

I dumped the whole schema and restored it on my local machine, and everything works as expected, but dropping from the production database and restoring again, did not fix the issue, the same scenario happens. That's why i can't provide a verifiable example, because I couldn't even reproduce it on another database.

What I noticed is that I can't alter the column structure, if I try running a `MODIFY` column on this exact column, changing anything at all, the query executes but the column stays the exact same. This don't happen with other columns on this same table.

Due to this extremely odd behaviour, I don't know anymore where to look or what is the underlying cause, I would suspect it's some kind of corruption on `information_schema` but I honestly don't have experience enough to be sure, neither to fix it.

If there's any lack of information, tell me in the comments and I will provide it as soon as possible.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Result from `desc myTable nincidusua`:

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|   Field    |  Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nincidusua | int(11) | NO   | PRI |       0 |       |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Why are you using backticks inconsistently? What is your `desc` showing?

Comment: Our database component generate with backticks to prevent possible spaces or reserved words, just a precaution. `desc` results are in the question

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable`, it is more descriptive than `DESC`.